# Using roles with jwt / zizaco/entrust

Tags: laravel-5, user-roles

In my new Laravel 5.8 app I read next article to use roles with jwt extention : 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/role-based-authentication-in-laravel-with-jwt
and in seed I add several roles, like :

```
\DB::table('roles')->insert(array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Admin',
            'display_name' => 'Admin',
            'description' => 'Administrator. Can do all operations in system',
            'created_at' => '2019-04-29 11:03:50',
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Manager',
            'display_name' => 'Manager. Can do all operations in frontend and CRUD for Hostels/CMS items in Backend',                         
            'description' => 'Manager description...',
            'created_at' => '2019-04-29 11:03:50',
        ),
    2 =>
        array (
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Customer',
            'display_name' => 'Customer. Can do all operations in frontend',
            'description' => 'Customer description...',
            'created_at' => '2019-04-29 11:03:50',
        ),
));
```

and I see  assignRole method, when I need to assign  some role to user.
What is unclear for me what for Permissions and “permission_role” data. 
Do I need them for my simple app structure? If yes, please provide some examples...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't answer your question if you don't specify what your application needs to do. You can have roles without permissions or permissions without roles depending on your application. But if you want the provided tutorial to work you need them.

Permissions are specific actions of a role.

Example Permisson table data:

```
Permission-id: 1
Permission-name: 'Create Blog Post'
```

You can assign this permission to a role 'Admin' (Role-id: 1).

Your permission_role table contains the relationship between those two. So for the above example:

```
permission_role
'permission_id': 1, 'role_id': 1;
```

Which means that The admin role can 'Create Blog Post' in this case.